# Not sure how to use implementation between two classes

Tags: java, interface, implementation

This is my class that everything is done in:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

//This class will not compile until all 
//abstract Locatable methods have been implemented
public class Block implements Locatable
{
    //instance variables
    private int xPos;
    private int yPos;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private Color color;

    //constructors
    public Block () {}

    public Block(int x,int y,int w,int h)
    {
        xPos = x;
        yPos = y;
        width = w;
        height = h;
    }

    public Block(int x,int y,int w,int h, Color c)
    {
        xPos = x;
        yPos = y;
        width = w;
        height = h;
        color = c;
    }

    //set methods
    public void setBlock(int x, int y, int w, int h)
    {
        xPos = x;
        yPos = y;
        width = w;
        height = h;
    }

    public void setBlock(int x, int y, int w, int h, Color c)
    {
        xPos = x;
        yPos = y;
        width = w;
        height = h;
        color = c;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics window)
    {
      window.setColor(color);
      window.fillRect(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

    //get methods
    public int getWidth()
    {
       return width;
    }

    public int getHeight()
    {
       return height;
    }

    //toString
    public String toString()
    {
       String complete = getX() + " " + getY() + " " + getWidth() + " " + getHeight() + " java.awt.Color[r=" +     color.getRed() + ", g=" + color.getGreen() + ", b=" + color.getBlue() + "]";
       return complete;
    }
}
```

and here is my interface class that has to be implemented:

```
public interface Locatable
{
    public void setPos( int x, int y);
    public void setX( int x );
    public void setY( int y );

    public int getX();
    public int getY();
}
```

I haven't had formal instruction yet on interfaces/implementations and thus, am not sure what needs to be done to get the first class to run right

Comment: How do I avoid getting an error like this: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The type Block must implement the inherited abstract method Locatable.getX()

 at Block.getX(Block.java:13)
 at Block.toString(Block.java:92)
 at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.PrintStream.println(Unknown Source)
 at BlockTestOne.main(BlockTestOne.java:15)`
in eclipse?

Comment: You need to implement the getX(), and the other methods in the Interface...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you implementing an interface, you have to implement all the methods declared in that interface.
**Interface is a contract that your implementing class must full fill**.in your case your implementing class **Block** should **implement** the following methods to full fill the contract.

```
public void setPos( int x, int y);
public void setX( int x );
public void setY( int y );

public int getX();
public int getY();

public class Block implements Locatable {
     public void setPos( int x, int y){
       // your implementatioon code
      }
      public void setX( int x ) {


        // your implementatioon code
      }
     public void setY( int y ){

 // your implementatioon code
}
public int getX(){


 // your implementatioon code
 return (an int value);
}
public int getY(){


 // your implementatioon code
  return (an int value);
}

}
```

EDIT: for your NPE from the comments.

you never initialized your Color object.and trying to call a method on its refrence in your toString method.

```
private Color color;
```

initialize it like this

```
 private Color color = new Color(any of the Color constructors);
```

check here for [Color API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html)

Comment: so add the `public int getX();` and `public int getY();` methods in the primary class near where my other accessor methods are? and the `Public void setX(int x);` and `public void setY(int y);` methods as modifiers?

Comment: shouldn't x and y be returned in the `getX()` and `getY()`?

Comment: @tech_geek23 yepp, ofcourse they have to cuz of the return type. i have edited it in the answer :)

Comment: Ok, I edited my own code before even pointing out the return in the answer above, but eclipse is noting that x and y are not variables, are the methods in the right locations? or should it be returning xPos and yPos accordingly?

Comment: @tech_geek23 i am assuming you are trying to set x value inside your setX method, you dont have x variable declared in your class, thus compile time error, i am assuming xPos purpose is to set the x value thru setX() and same applies for yPos .

Comment: so like `Color(0,0,0)`, right? it's been a while since I've dealt with colors

Comment: @tech_geek23 i am not familiar with java.awt package. please refer to the API. :)

Comment: ok, I did, that seems to resolve what was wrong. I think I just need to change some default values for x,y,width, and height now since it's not supposed to be 0,0,0,0 when not given in the constructor

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this is only part 1 of this lab...... I'll be sure and post again if I hit any issues on part 2